# How to make a many-to-one relationship in DDD with strongly type Id in .NET with EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I faced an issue when I created a many-To-One relationship between two entities, I needed to make that class have many students in one class.

Here are my classes:

```
public sealed class Class: AggregateRoot<ClassId, int>
{
    private readonly List<Student.Student> _students = new();
    public BranchId BranchId { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Student.Student> Students => _students.AsReadOnly(); 

    private Class(ClassId id, 
                  BranchId branchId,
                  DateTime startDate,
                  DateTime endDate,
                  List<Student.Student> students,
                  DateTime createdDateTime,
                  DateTime updatedDateTime): base(id)
    {
        BranchId = branchId;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
        _students = students;
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
        UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    public static Class Create(BranchId branchId,
                               DateTime startDate,
                               DateTime endDate,
                               List<Student.Student> students)
    {
        return new Class(id: null!,
                         branchId,
                         startDate,
                         endDate, 
                         students,
                         DateTime.Now,
                         DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static Class Update(int id, 
                               BranchId branchId,
                               DateTime startDate,
                               DateTime endDate,
                               List<Student.Student> students,
                               ref Class classObj)
    {
        return classObj = new Class(id: ClassId.Create(id), 
                                    branchId,
                                    startDate,
                                    endDate,
                                    students,
                                    classObj.CreatedDateTime,
                                    DateTime.Now);
    }

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    private Class() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618
}
```

```
public sealed class Student: AggregateRoot<StudentId, int>
{
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string? Email { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public BeltId BeltId { get; set; }
    public BranchId BranchId { get; private set; }
    public ClassId ClassId { get; private set; }
    public string Status { get; private set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; private set; }

    private Student(StudentId id,
                   string fullName,
                   string? email,
                   string password,
                   BeltId beltId,
                   BranchId branchId,
                   ClassId classId,
                   string status,
                   string imageUrl, 
                   DateTime createdDateTime,
                   DateTime updatedDateTime) : base(id)
    {
        FullName = fullName;
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
        BeltId = beltId;
        BranchId = branchId;
        Status = status;
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        ClassId = classId;
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
        UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    public static Student Create(string fullName,
                                 string email,
                                 string password,
                                 int beltId,
                                 BranchId branchId,
                                 ClassId classId,
                                 string status,
                                 string imageUrl)
    {
        return new Student(id: null!,
                           fullName: fullName,
                           email: email.ToLower(),
                           beltId: BeltId.Create(beltId),
                           password: password,
                           branchId: branchId,
                           classId: classId,
                           status: status,
                           imageUrl: imageUrl,
                           createdDateTime: DateTime.Now,
                           updatedDateTime: DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static Student Update(int id,
                                 string fullName,
                                 string email,
                                 int beltId,
                                 BranchId branchId,
                                 ClassId classId,
                                 string status,
                                 string imageUrl,
                                 ref Student student)
    {
        return student = new Student(id: StudentId.Create(id),
                                    fullName: fullName,
                                    email: email.ToLower(),
                                    beltId: BeltId.Create(beltId),
                                    password: student.Password,
                                    branchId: branchId,
                                    classId: classId,
                                    status: status,
                                    imageUrl: imageUrl,
                                    createdDateTime: student.CreatedDateTime,
                                    updatedDateTime: DateTime.Now);
    }

#pragma warning disable CS8618
    private Student() { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618
}
```

And here are my configurations:

```
public class StudentConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Students");

        builder.HasKey(s => s.Id);

        builder.Property(s => s.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value,
                value => StudentId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(s => s.ClassId)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value,
                value => ClassId.Create(value));

        builder.HasIndex(s => s.Id);

        builder.HasIndex(s => s.FullName).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(s => s.FullName).HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.Property(s => s.Password);
        builder.Property(s => s.ImageUrl);
        builder.Property(s => s.Email).HasMaxLength(64);

        builder.Property(s => s.CreatedDateTime);
        builder.Property(s => s.UpdatedDateTime);

        builder.Property(s => s.BranchId)
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value,
                value => BranchId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(s => s.BeltId)
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value,
                value => BeltId.Create(value));
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassConfigurations: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Class>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Class> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Classes");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id); 

        builder.Property(c => c.Id)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
               .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => ClassId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(c => c.BranchId)
               .HasConversion(
                    id => id.Value,
                    value => BranchId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(c => c.EndDate); 
        builder.Property(c => c.StartDate);

        builder.HasMany<Student>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(s => s.ClassId); 
    }
}
```

But when I try to applied these configurations, EF Core showed this error

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The relationship from 'Student' to 'Class' with foreign key properties {'ClassId' : ClassId} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : AggregateRootId} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Please how can I solve this issue?

Here are some clarification:

- Class has many Students
- Student has one class

Thanks all

Comment: The EF class model should be simple. It's part of a data access layer, it's not a domain model. Which means: first objective is to make EF's life easy. EF doesn't like these typed primary keys.